# Google Chrome crashing on launch, OS X Yosemite Public Beta 2

Tags: google-chrome, beta, osx-yosemite

Just recently updated to the 2nd release of OS X Yosemite's public beta. A few hours into using it, I had Chrome crash, and refuse to start up subsequently. The strange thing is, Eclipse isn't working now either, and both are throwing similar crash reports (Exception Type:        EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
Exception Codes:       KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x000000000bf001cc  for both programs).

I'm attaching part of the crash report - I'd greatly appreciate it if someone could enlighten me as to how I can possibly solve this issue.

TIA!

-Karim

```
Process:               Google Chrome [517]
Path:                  /Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome
Identifier:            com.google.Chrome
Version:               36.0.1985.143 (1985.143)
Code Type:             X86 (Native)
Parent Process:        ??? [1]
Responsible:           Google Chrome [517]
User ID:               501

Date/Time:             2014-08-23 23:20:13.984 +0300
OS Version:            Mac OS X 10.10 (14A329r)
Report Version:        11
Anonymous UUID:        2B3EC928-2881-8966-016D-22F741C8F171


Time Awake Since Boot: 770 seconds

Crashed Thread:        0  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread

Exception Type:        EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
Exception Codes:       KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x000000000bf001cc

VM Regions Near 0xbf001cc:
    MALLOC (admin)         00000000060e4000-00000000060e5000 [    4K] ---/rwx SM=NUL  
--> 
    MALLOC_TINY            000000007a600000-000000007a800000 [ 2048K] rw-/rwx SM=PRV  

Thread 0 Crashed:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
0   com.apple.AppKit                0x9b902227 +[NSResponder initialize] + 18
1   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x955a92c3 _class_initialize + 502
2   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x955a90fe _class_initialize + 49
3   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x955a90fe _class_initialize + 49
4   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x955b138e lookUpImpOrForward + 117
5   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x955a906e _class_lookupMethodAndLoadCache3 + 55
6   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x955a50e1 objc_msgSend + 81
7   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x955a9e3d call_load_methods + 760
8   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x955a8f6d load_images + 63
9   dyld                            0x8fe51e6b dyld::notifySingle(dyld_image_states, ImageLoader const*) + 271
10  dyld                            0x8fe602dc ImageLoader::recursiveInitialization(ImageLoader::LinkContext const&, unsigned int, ImageLoader::InitializerTimingList&, ImageLoader::UninitedUpwards&) + 276
11  dyld                            0x8fe60288 ImageLoader::recursiveInitialization(ImageLoader::LinkContext const&, unsigned int, ImageLoader::InitializerTimingList&, ImageLoader::UninitedUpwards&) + 192
12  dyld                            0x8fe60176 ImageLoader::processInitializers(ImageLoader::LinkContext const&, unsigned int, ImageLoader::InitializerTimingList&, ImageLoader::UninitedUpwards&) + 120
13  dyld                            0x8fe603e1 ImageLoader::runInitializers(ImageLoader::LinkContext const&, ImageLoader::InitializerTimingList&) + 79
14  dyld                            0x8fe52125 dyld::initializeMainExecutable() + 183
15  dyld                            0x8fe55bad dyld::_main(macho_header const*, unsigned long, int, char const**, char const**, char const**, unsigned long*) + 2793
16  dyld                            0x8fe51232 dyldbootstrap::start(macho_header const*, int, char const**, long, macho_header const*, unsigned long*) + 428
17  dyld                            0x8fe51047 _dyld_start + 71

Thread 0 crashed with X86 Thread State (32-bit):
  eax: 0x9b902220  ebx: 0x955a90db  ecx: 0x0000e80c  edx: 0x00000000
  edi: 0xa0999992  esi: 0xa0f06b54  ebp: 0xbff969a8  esp: 0xbff969a0
   ss: 0x00000023  efl: 0x00010286  eip: 0x9b902227   cs: 0x0000001b
   ds: 0x00000023   es: 0x00000023   fs: 0x00000000   gs: 0x0000000f
  cr2: 0x0bf001cc
  
Logical CPU:     0
Error Code:      0x00000004
Trap Number:     14


Binary Images:
   0x68000 -    0x68ff3 +com.google.Chrome (36.0.1985.143 - 1985.143) <F977D730-6DFF-3F1C-A9DA-191F9698F00E> /Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome
   0x6d000 -  0x45e4fbb +com.google.Chrome.framework (36.0.1985.143 - 1985.143) <BCE7F3F9-D9F4-3494-A1BB-FF0E38406F8C> /Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/Versions/36.0.1985.143/Google Chrome Framework.framework/Google Chrome Framework
 0x4961000 -  0x499aff7  com.apple.audio.midi.CoreMIDI (1.10 - 88) <562B7796-CAAD-3BAA-A64A-B7FB8CE0E7FA> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreMIDI.framework/Versions/A/CoreMIDI
 0x49be000 -  0x4c22ff7  com.apple.AddressBook.framework (8.0 - 1485) <A40C801F-9BAF-379B-B530-8CAD867A1809> /System/Library/Frameworks/AddressBook.framework/Versions/A/AddressBook
 0x4dd4000 -  0x4e2cff3  com.apple.ImageCaptureCore (6.0 - 6.0) <9DEEBD46-DF75-393C-8493-9BE7F6071E54> /System/Library/Frameworks/ImageCaptureCore.framework/Versions/A/ImageCaptureCore
 0x4e5b000 -  0x4e8cff7  com.apple.securityinterface (10.0 - 55053) <060EA66C-CA71-3314-BBB2-0B8CD838B372> /System/Library/Frameworks/SecurityInterface.framework/Versions/A/SecurityInterface
 0x4ead000 -  0x4eadfff  com.apple.quartzframework (1.5 - 1.5) <F4580C44-C3FC-37EF-B373-A594987C892F> /System/Library/Frameworks/Quartz.framework/Versions/A/Quartz
```

Comment: Just realised that the whole MS Office suite stopped launching as a result of this as well - making this issue a bit more urgent!

Answer (score 1):

Some apparently fixed the issue via this command :

```
sudo chown -R $USER ~/Library/Google
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem when I upgraded to Yosemite. For me, it was fixed by uninstalling and reinstalling Chrome. I don't use Eclipse, so I can't speak to how it might be resolved.

Answer (score 0):

https://www.reddit.com/r/apple/comments/2n721c/temporary_fix_for_chrome_crash_in_yosemite_10102/

which is.

Put the following in a file "patch.m":

```
#import <AppKit/AppKit.h>

__attribute((constructor)) void Patch_10_10_2_entry()
{
    NSLog(@"10.10.2 patch loaded");
}

@interface NSTouch ()
- (id)_initWithPreviousTouch:(NSTouch *)touch newPhase:(NSTouchPhase)phase position:(CGPoint)position isResting:(BOOL)isResting force:(double)force;
@end

@implementation NSTouch (Patch_10_10_2)
- (id)_initWithPreviousTouch:(NSTouch *)touch newPhase:(NSTouchPhase)phase position:(CGPoint)position isResting:(BOOL)isResting
{
    return [self _initWithPreviousTouch:touch newPhase:phase position:position isResting:isResting force:0];
}
@end
```

Compile it:

```
clang -dynamiclib -framework AppKit patch.m -o patch.dylib
```

Use it:

```
env DYLD_INSERT_LIBRARIES=/path/to/patch.dylib "/path/to/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome"
```

You can't close the process but if you don't want extra dock items, leave it in a detached tmux (or similar) session.